# x86 Instruction help: MOV [edx], eax

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I'm reading through a book that is describing C linked lists and how they are represented within x86 ASM. I having difficulty understanding the instruction `MOV [edx], eax`.

If the instruction was reversed, `MOV eax, [edx]`, I would understand it to mean copy the 4 bytes represented by the memory address stored in edx and store it in eax.

What does MOV `[edx], eax` represent?

If using the `[]` with the `MOV` instruction, I thought it meant to copy the data residing at the memory address to it's destination. If that is true, how can you copy whatever is in `eax` to a data value in `edx`?

Comment: Simple answer, writing the equivalent in C:   * ((DWORD*)EDX)=EAX;

Comment: @chuck - It works exactly the same, just in the other direction.

Answer (score 20):

It's Intel assembly syntax. In Intel assembly syntax the destination is always the first operand, the rest operands are source operands. The other commonly used assembly syntax for x86 is AT&T, but as Intel and AT&T syntaxes look very different, they are easy to distinguish.

`mov [edx],eax` stores the value of `eax` in memory, to the address given in `edx` (in little-endian byte order).

`mov eax,[edx]` does exactly the reverse, reads a value stored from the memory, from the address given in `edx`, and stores it in `eax`.

`[reg]` always means indirect addressing, it's just like a pointer `*reg` in C.

To copy the contents of `eax` to `edx`, all you need is `mov edx,eax`. Destination is first operand, source is the second operand.